# How to generate a 2d grid from a set of randomly generated coordinates?

Tags: python, random, grid, 2d

The plan for the use of this is in a text based Space RPG game. I want to generate random points (x,y coordinates) - which I have already done - followed by plotting them with connections shown on a 2d grid. As a side, how would I label these coordinates?

**The code for the random generation is included below:**

```
import time
import random
import math

radius = 200
rangeX = (0, 2500)
rangeY = (0, 2500)
qty = 40 

deltas = set()
for x in range(-radius, radius+1):
    for y in range(-radius, radius+1):
        if x*x + y*y <= radius*radius:
            deltas.add((x,y))

randPoints = []
excluded = set()
i = 0
while i<qty:
    x = random.randrange(*rangeX)
    y = random.randrange(*rangeY)
    if (x,y) in excluded: continue
    randPoints.append((x,y))
    i += 1
    excluded.update((x+dx, y+dy) for (dx,dy) in deltas)
    time.sleep(0.001)

stars = {}
keyName = 1
for item in randPoints:
    stars[str(keyName)] = [item, 0,]
    keyName += 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by a 2d grid?

Comment: I was wanting to generate an image of a 2 dimensional grid with x and y coordinates, like a map. @martineau

Comment: Are you trying to find a path to the random x,y coordinates from a given point? I don't understand what do you mean by plotting them with connections shown on 2d grid.

Comment: I am trying to design a mainly text based RPG game. I was looking for a way to take my randomly generated points(or "stars") and show them as part of a map, with visual aids - connecting lines maybe - between stars less than "n" distance apart. A map basically.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an example of what the grid might look like (since apparently it's text).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing you with a direct answer I will point you in a general direction as the scope of this question seems rather big.

Consider using pygame; it provides you with drawing functions, has an event system that you can use to detect user input and has many other helpful features for creating games as the name suggests.

Strongly consider using classes; your code will become more readable and more flexible. Adding features to your stars such as a label, surface temperature, color of emitted (pulsing?) light, available raw materials.. etc. becomes much easier to handle.

To generate names you could put existing star names in a text file, load it and pick one at random. For added bonus points use a markov chain to generate seemingly random names.

https://www.pygame.org

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain